# Set to web view on top while it load next data in same web view.

Tags: android, scroll, webview

Am using web view for display some part of received data from server in my Android app and load next some data after pressing next button but it point to same location at which position user left previous page instead of top position.

I have used to scrollTo() and getTop() methods but no success using these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using WebView inside NestedScrollView so above two method was not working for WebView .Now i have applied code for NestedScrollView and it is working perfectly.

For scroll up to web view on next page click use:

```
nestedScrollView.fullScroll(nestedScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
```